# $f$ continous in $[a,b]$, differentiable in $(a,b)$ (where $b>a>0$) such that $f(a)/a=f(b)/b$

Tags: calculus

Prove that there exist $x_0\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(x_0)=\dfrac{f(x_0)}{x_0}$

I tried by using Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem for $f(x)$ in $(a,b)$ which gave me
$$f'(c)=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \ \text{for some } c\in (a,b)$$

From condition provided in question it get reduced to
$f'(c)= \dfrac{f(a)}a$
but I am not getting what's asked in the question.

Comment: Kindly use Mathjax to edit the math in your question and make it more readable.

Comment: Please include all the hypotheses in the body of the question, as well.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**: Consider the function $g(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}x$. Then $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ (why?). You know that $g(a)=g(b)$, and so ...

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add a graphical representation of the problem

[image]

Comment: Very nice. While geometrical arguments can not be considered as rigorous proofs of analytical theorems, I would still categorize your image as a "proof without words". +1